# Excel formula to convert self to value?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible for a formula in excel to return a value and assign it to itself, overwriting the formula?

Example: If column A consists of

`=IF(LEN(B2)>0,"1","0")`

On cell contents in B2, I want the value of A2 to become 1, and remain 1, regardless of change to B2.

While if B2 is empty, A2 shall be 0 only while B2 remains empty.

Comment: You can do that with a "paste special - values".  Select column A and copy it, then "paste special" and pick "values" and select the target to be the same column A.  Likewise if you can do that you can also do it with a macro.  I don't think there is a way to use a formula that destroys itself.

Comment: @Tyson, why use a comment? Put it in an answer.

Comment: @teylyn every time I do that with an "alternate answer" it gets down voted. My comment is a method to achieve the desired result but it doesn't answer the question asked, and makes assumptions-- I've learned not to ASSume anything on this site.